# What does John Stuart Mill mean when writing the following:

Tags: complex-sentences, nineteenth-century-english

> Those who admit any limit to what a government may do, except in the
>   case of such governments as they think ought not to exist, stand out as
>   brilliant exceptions among the political thinkers of the Continent. A
>   similar tone of sentiment might by this time have been prevalent in our
>   own country, if the circumstances which for a time encouraged it, had
>   continued unaltered.

What does the phrase "except in the case of such governments as they think ought not to exist" mean? Does he mean these thinkers have some government preference?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: How have you attempted to parse it?

Comment: What does the phrase "except in the case of such governments as they think ought not to exist" mean. Does he mean these thinkers have some government preference?

Comment: Break down that phrase into its constituents.  Diagram it, if need be.

Comment: This is really a question for the *politics*, or the *history* site. I assume it is taken from *On Liberty* which was published in 1859. Those governments that "they think ought not to exist", will, one supposes, have been republican administrations, such as the French Third Empire.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. It does not identify a single term or construction for analysis, but addresses overall comprehension.

Comment: they=the  political thinkers. That should clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Mill means is, it was rare to find someone in mainland Europe who believed that there should have limits on the powers of a particular government, unless he also believed that that particular government should not have existed at all. Most people would have granted the governments that they liked plenary authority.

(His claim that British intellectuals were more impartial I find... over-optimistic.)

To put it modern terms, lots of people believe that Donald Trump's authority should be sharply limited -- but how many of them also believed that Barack Obama's authority should have been similarly limited?